# TabItem and DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TabControl with 2 TabItems: the main one containing a Listbox ; the 2nd one has controls to display detail of the listbox selected item. This works perfectly.
Now, I want to move all my layout for 2nd TabItem to a ResourceDictionary which contains all my DataTemplates, so I've set the TabItem like this:
`<TabItem ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemEditTemplate}">`
The template is well displayed but all the bindings don't work anymore!....
Why ?
In the output window, I get several errors from binding properties saying: "property xxxxx cannot be found on 'Grid' (the grid is the root of my template).
How to solve this ?

Note: TabItem 2 DataContext is set by code (to the Listbox.SelectedItem)

To be clearer, here's how things are set up:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Name="TabItem1">
    <Listbox />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Name="TabItem2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemEditTemplate}" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You have to set the DataContext of your Grid to the Listbox.SelectedItem.

Comment: I've set the grid datacontext like this: `<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem}, Path=DataContext.Data}">`, since the TabItem's DataContext is already the Listbox.SelectedItem, but same issue... How could I get access the Listbox from my Datatemplate since it's in another TabItem ?

Comment: I can't understand why the Grid does'nt take its DataContext from the control it's nested in.. Whatever I put in the DataContext, it always throws errrors 'property xxxx cannot be found on 'Grid' ', as if Grid was always the topest level of the tree...